# Brouwer's fixed-point theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems, group-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, pullback

I'm trying to understand the cohomological proof of this theorem, but I'm stuck at a point, which brings me to ask a more general question: let $i:Z\rightarrow X$ be the inclusion of a closed set into a topological space. If there exists a continuous map $r$ such that $r\circ i=1$, is it true that the induced map on sheaf cohomology groups $$i^*:H^n(X,\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow H^n(Z,i^* \mathbb{Z})$$is surjective? Why?

Comment: hint: a function $f:X\to Y$ is surjective if and only if there exists $g:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g = id$.

Comment: Ah so i guess I can compose with $r^*$, since $(r\circ i)^*=i^*\circ r^*$...

Comment: @podiki just as a remark, the only if part is the axiom of choice. But no matter your stance on that axiom, the if part is always true.

Comment: @podiki This is true for functions between sets, but not for continuous maps between topological spaces.

Comment: @PaulFrost What is the corresponding statement that is not true for topological spaces?

Comment: @podiki If $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous surjection, then in general there is no continuous $g : Y \to X$ such that $f \circ g = id$.